# PHP - Getting request variable with a file extension doesn't work

Tags: php, gif

```
$badgedata = $_GET['badge'];
if ($badgedata == "test.gif") {
  $im = imagecreatefromgif("badges/base/test.gif");
  imagegif($im);
}
```

why does this display a blank page when I go to

```
badge.php?badge=test.gif
```

But if i try

```
$badgedata = $_GET['badge'];
if ($badgedata == "test") {
  $im = imagecreatefromgif("badges/base/test.gif");
  imagegif($im);
}
```

and go to

```
badge.php?badge=test
```

it works, but I need the `.gif` on the end.

Comment: I imagine you have a mod_rewrite rule in your htaccess doing something stupid.

Comment: header is set further up in the file
header("Content-type: image/gif");

Comment: Have you tried to decode the "." in the url als "%2E" ? I never used a "." in Get params, perhaps this is the problam.

Comment: @AlucardTheRipper tried that and it didnt work

Comment: @ItsJamie No need to specify "PHP" in the title of the question when you have it tagged

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you request "badge.php?badge=test.gif&x"? If not, I would tend to agree with AlienWebguy that it's probably a rewrite rule or something kicking in because the URL ends with a .gif extension.

Answer (score 0):

you must set header

```
$badgedata = $_GET['badge'];
if ($badgedata == "test.gif") {
   $im = imagecreatefromgif("badges/base/test.gif");
   header('Content-Type: image/gif');
   imagegif($im);
}
```

check badge value

```
$badgedata = $_GET['badge'];
echo $badgedata;
```

Comment: I have already set the header further up in the file I need it to have .gif at the end of it when it is checking the badgedata

Comment: badge.php?badge=test works

but i need badge.php?badge=test.gif to work

Comment: when I goto badge.php?badge=test.gif it doesnt work, I need this to work

Comment: i change `if` condition see answer

Comment: if without dot work but with dot not work maybe you have a htaccess code that change dot put `echo $badgedata;` at end see the result and send us

Comment: when i try and echo the badgedata while having test.gif it still gives me a blank page there is nothing in my htaccess for the badge.php

Comment: i put  echo in answer check again

Comment: if value is different from your input you must put htaccess on your question. 99% problem is on  htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

URL

```
?badge=test%2Egif
```

Code

```
<?php
$badge = (isset($_GET['badge'])) ? urldecode($_GET['badge']) : null;
if(!empty($badge))
echo $badge;
```

Comment: I need it to .gif because a shockwave game needs to read it as .gif